# intellij navigation(back/forward) within one file

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation

intellij: how to navigate(back/forward) within one file instead of jumping between files. The purpose is to go to a previous location of a file, and it is not needed to navigate to any other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`<-`</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`->`</kbd> keys on Windows/*Nix, and on macOs <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> adn <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to navigate on the same file.

Note: This will move to other files once the navigation reached the end on the particular file.

Comment: not working for windows 10. It turns the screen display 90 degree clockwise

Comment: it does work work for me, do you/@eastwater have Intel Graphics Driver? AFAIK it has an shorcut for rotating the screen, maybe you can disable that? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005491/graphics.html